# Can a single word be an idiom or an expression?

Tags: expressions, idioms, differences

Can a single word be considered an idiom or an expression? If so, how does one tell the difference?
For instance, words like, "dope!", "lit!", "sick!". These words mean completely different things than their original meaning when used in a certain way/context, "sick" means ill but in a certain context can mean "excellent". There are also words like, "cathouse", which have nothing to do with cats.

Are these words idioms or expressions? Confusingly, [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/expression) says an idiom  is an expression.

The website, *[Difference Between.net](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-phrase-and-idiom/)*, says

> Phrases can be taken literally while idioms are not literal in their meaning but figurative. Idioms can also be called colloquial metaphors.  Another significant difference is that **a phrase is always a group of words but a single word can on occasions be an idiom.**  For example: *moonlighting*, a single word meaning something different in the way it is used and it does not have anything to do with moonlight.

Visitors to *[UsingEnglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/poll/475.html)* are invited to express their opinions on its language polls. In this instance, the question was **Can a single word be an idiom?**
The results are shown in the graphic below.
70.99 % of voters replied “Yes".

[image]

A clear definition that shows the distinction between idiom and expression would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have an answer that I might post, but I am waiting for some of our better grammarians to wake up or get back from services.

Comment: Single words can't be idioms, but they can occur (perhaps only) in idiomatic expressions. The term "expression" seems to refer (not technically) to any frequently-repeated string of words, whatever its source or structure.

Comment: **Idioms** are a subclass of [multi-word] expressions, necessarily including unusual word usage, grammar, or both, and also being idiomatic (generally accepted). Most would allow single words to be classed as expressions, but not as idioms. // But basic research is required.

Comment: Words can have multiple meanings, which change over time. Some new meanings may be added to word X, some meanings of X may go out of fashion. [[ Multiple words put together make Idioms, where the meanings of Idioms can not be deduced through these words. ]] When word X is used outside of the accepted meanings, we might say that X has got a new (maybe temporary) meaning. I am not exactly sure in what way we can say that it is a new Idiom. I would consider it Slang, Interjection, or Expression, but not Idiom.

Comment: Agree with John. An idiom is never a single word.

Comment: Well gosh...I didn't know that, and since I could not answer in comment and had to look it up, I thought it an interesting Q. .. I learned something today, and any day I  can learn something new it is a good day. Voted to 'remain open'

Comment: I think you're confusing *slang* with the more formal meanings of words e.g. He is sick (he's not well) vs That's sick! (excellent) Both forms are idiomatic, both consist of a single word, but "sick" by itself is not an idiom.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  "idomatic" is defined on dictionary.cambridge.org is a word consisting or made up of "idioms". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiomatic

Comment: idiomatic is not the same as an idiom. The idiom  "break a leg"  can be a metaphor for good luck or a literal command. If I replace the *idiom* with its Italian equivalent "in the wolf's mouth" the former meaning is lost, and my listener will look at me confused. If I replaced *break* with *snap* i.e. "snap a leg" although it is understandable it is no longer an idiom. Look up a list of English idioms and if you can find a single-word idiom you can post it as answer! Here's a link: https://leverageedu.com/blog/idioms-with-examples/

Comment: @Mari-LouA This is debated, and I mentioned it in my edits because of this reason. I had actually already researched the pole before your inclusion of it in the question. Which is why I was intrigued and wanted to post the question. Judging from the pole itself alone, it still seems to be something that is highly argued. And the reason I posted the comment was to indicate there exist this definition from cambridge dictionary. Not to depate the topic. Regardless, Thank you for making it possible for the question to remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a single word be considered an idiom or an expression?

From Lexico:

[**Expression**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/expression)

> 3. /count noun/ A ***word*** or phrase, *especially an idiomatic one*, used to convey an idea.
>    ‘we have an expression, ‘You don't get owt for nowt.’’

So an expression is a commonly used set and fixed  word or phrase to illustrate a concept.

Ex. of phrases

> 'To make a long story short'
> 'Your guess is as good as mine'
> 'As rich as Croesus'

Ex. of single words

> 'Great'!
> 'What'?
> 'Yuck'

These are common expressions which are understandable and literal, even when broken down into parts. In fact, most any often repeated word or phrase can be an expression. It is a very general grouping.

On the other hand, if an expression cannot be understood on its own in a literal sense, it becomes an idiom...

Lexico says that ...

[**Idiom**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/idiom)

> 1. (is) A ***group of words*** established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words (e.g. over the moon, see the light).

Examples of idiomatic expressions

> 'over his head'
> 'to steal someone's thunder'
> 'Don't put all your eggs in one basket'

These are constituents, cannot be broken down, and are usually non-literal.

---

[MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/expression) says mostly the same:

**Expression**

> (countable) a **word** or phrase

**Idiom**

> (countable ​linguistics) an **expression** whose meaning is *different from the meaning of the individual words*. For example, ‘to have your feet on the ground’ is an idiom meaning ‘to be sensible’.

[All emphasis mine]

...and ditto [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom) .

This would seem to indicate that 'idiom' can be seen as a subset of 'expression', but they are not necessarily the same thing.

So strictly speaking, I would say that interjections like...

> "dope!", "lit!", "sick!"

...are expressions with idiomatic meanings, but they are not idioms, and *in fact single words cannot be idioms*, as [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) points out in comment.

> Single words can't be idioms, but they can occur (perhaps only) in idiomatic expressions. The term "expression" seems to refer (not technically) to any frequently-repeated string of words, whatever its source or structure.

---

Evidently, there is a linguistics term that might help bridge the gap between these words...

***Multi-word expressions***

> ...are linguistic objects formed by two or more words that behave like a ‘unit’ by displaying formal and/or functional idiosyncratic properties with respect to free word combinations. They include an extremely varied set of items (from idioms to collocations, from formulae to sayings)

[Oxford Research Encyclopedia](https://oxfordre.com/linguistics/linguistics/view/10.1093/acrefore/9780199384655.001.0001/acrefore-9780199384655-e-611)

Comment: BTW, this answer was posted before the 'answers _in comment_'

Comment: Could you please add to this very well written answer, a clear distinction between expression and idioms with examples. As that would complete the question's answer. Would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: @ShahzadRahim I have added some more examples with explanations...I hope this clears up any remaining confusion...

Comment: I think you rushed to judge that. I just opened the website and read your added details to the answer. I was obviously looking forward to your newly added explanations and examples before submitting feedback.

Comment: Thank you--again, for understanding the true value of the question and contributing towards a comprehensive answer. I hope that suffices to show my appreciation.

Comment: Sorry...I was thinking more on the work that Mari-Lou A A put into revising your post...she did a phenomenal job trying to keep it on-topic. You might want to give her a shout out.